# LARAVEL 8: General error: 1005 occured while running migration with foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-8

I want to run a migration called `articles` which goes like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->refrence('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->string('imageUrl');
        $table->string('tags');
        $table->integer('viewCount')->default(0);
        $table->integer('commentCount')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

But I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `gooyanet`.`#sql-1ce8_1d` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `articles` add constraint `articles_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

So I searched over the net and they say I have to create tables first and then add the foreign keys, so I wrote this instead:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->string('imageUrl');
        $table->string('tags');
        $table->integer('viewCount')->default(0);
        $table->integer('commentCount')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::table('articles', function($table)
    {
        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

But now the error is this:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'gooyanet.articles' doesn't exist (SQL: alter table `articles` add constraint `articles_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

So what should I do in order to run this migration with foreign key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default **[Laravel 8](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)**  uses `unsignedBigInteger` as foreign key :

```
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

**Alternative** : Laravel provides additional, terser methods that use convention to provide a better developer experience. The example above could be written like so :

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
```